# Why is the Mono type needed in Reactor 3?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

Reactor 3 has 2 primary data types both of which are reactive stream publishers

- `reactor.core.publisher.Mono<T>`
- `reactor.core.publisher.Flux<T>`

I understand the difference between Mono being a stream of 0 or 1 elements and Flux being a stream of 0 or N elements.

Since both Mono and Flush are implementing `org.reactivestreams.Publisher<T>` why do we need both types why not just use Flux for everything?

Comment: It's just semantic for developer to know what behavior to expect from the publisher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mono vs Flux in Reactive Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988433/mono-vs-flux-in-reactive-stream)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about what happens in the non-reactive world: we could decide to make all the functions return `List<T>`, even when we know they will only return a single element. Example:

```
public List<T> findAll()     <-- looks ok

public List<T> findFirst()   <-- seems strange?

public T findFirst()         <-- better now?
```

So why don't we always return `List<T>`? because it's more convenient that sometimes we use `List<T>` and others simply `T`, this way it is easier on the user of the function to understand what to expect.

Now if we convert these examples to the reactive world, we get this:

```
public List<T> findAll()   -->   public Flux<T> findAll()

public T findFirst()       -->   public Mono<T> findFirst()
```

Sure, we could always use `Flux<T>` as we could always use `List<T>`, but it is just more convenient to be able to differentiate when there multiple items or just one.