# When to use Mono<List<Object>> and when Flux<Object> for RestController method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I'm using Spring web-flux with Reactor and for me is not clear when RestController method should return

`Mono <List<Object>>` and when  `Flux<Object>`.

Could you provide some case when to use each of them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Flux<Object>` indicates that new `Object` instances can be pushed in a reactive way at any point. With `Mono<List<Object>>`, you will get 1 time a value that is a list of objects, but that list will never change.

See also [Mono vs Flux in Reactive Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988433/mono-vs-flux-in-reactive-stream)

Comment: So in case of a normal API exposed by a Spring RestController, assuming this API will expose a list of items (users' owned cars, for example), reading at your response I should choose `Mono<List<Object>>` instead of `Flux<Object>` because I'm just waiting for "1 time a value that is a list of objects". Is this correct?

Comment: The answer to your question is: yes, that's correct.